# Delaying a schedule task

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, scheduled-tasks

I have a schedule task i.e mytask on 50of my computers(windows) and i am working on writing a batch file to delay the task by 2 min on all 50 computers, is this the right way to go about it ? I come across this on microsoft website.

```
schtasks /Change 
[/S system [/U system [/P [password]]]] /TN taskname
{ [/RU runasuser] [/RP runaspassword] [/TR taskrun] [/ST starttime] 
[/RI interval] [ {/ET endtime | /DU duration} [/K] ]
[/SD startdate] [/ED enddate] [/ENABLE | /DISABLE] [/IT] [/Z] }
```

Comment: This is just the arguments for schtasks. What have you tried and where is the [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Powershell [jobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_jobs?view=powershell-6) in combination with PowerShell [remoting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_remote?view=powershell-6). Some pseudo code:

```
  $session = New-PSSession -Computer "yourComputerNameOrIp" -Credential (Get-Credential)
  Invoke-Command -Session $session -Scriptblock { Write-Host "$($env:COMPUTERNAME)"
```

[Here](https://blog.netspi.com/powershell-remoting-cheatsheet/) you'll also find a description of how to enable Powershell remoting.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi @Karma if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.